# Assigning calendar delegates but blocking prior calendar history in Outlook with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook, delegates, office365

The company I work for wants to assign calendar delegates in Outlook but doesn't want the new delegates to see calendar history prior to that person becoming a delegate. I found the code that will assign the delegates:

```
add-mailboxpermission -identity <owner of calendar>:\calendar -user 
<person whom delegate permission is given to> -accessrights Editor - 
sharingpermissionflags Delegate
```

Does anybody know of a way to prevent the new delegates from seeing calendar history?

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!
- @Leah_CyberPadawan

Comment: This is not a feature that Outlook provides. The best you could do is mark all previous meetings as private which will also hide them from other delegates. The delegate wont be able to modify the previous meetings anyway as they were not the meeting organizer.

Comment: @DrewLean I thought that might be the case, thanks so much for your input!